# Preventing html ENTER event without disabling keypress

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, element, onkeypress

I'm building a spreadsheet site using `<tr contenteditable="true">` for cells.

I've implemented an `onkeyup` function whereby pressing `enter` when focused on a cell shifts focus to the next cell directly below, but the problem is that pressing `enter` by default also adds a line break with `contenteditable` elements, resulting in an empty line being created before moving on the next cell.

[image]

Both fire at the same time, so I don't have a chance to cancel the keypress without also breaking my function. All of the solutions I've found involve completely disabling the enter key when focused on the element, but that won't work here since my function relies on being able to press enter while focused on the element.

**All I need is for the `tr` to not insert a** `<br>` **on enter, I do not need to disable my enter key.**

Comment: At the start of the keydown function have you tried doing e.preventDefault()?

Comment: Yes but that disables text input preventing me from typing anything in the cells. The skipRow() function still works though.

Comment: don't disable it for all keys, check if the key is enter before doing preventDefault

Comment: Thank worked! Just had to also make sure I was doing onkeypress/down instead of onkeyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `e.preventDefault()` on `enter` events solved the issue. Make sure you only put it on the `enter` key and not for all keypresses otherwise you will disable text input for the cells preventing you from being able to edit them, and make sure to use `onkeypress/onkeydown` and not `onkeyup`.

Big thanks to @Robin Clower and @Zac in the comments.